# MySQL Order By multiple columns with Case End sort number as string

Tags: mysql

Want to do a select with following order by.

```
... ...
order by
    case when t1.a is not null 
         then t1.a 
         else concat(t2.b, ',', t2.c)
    end asc;
```

The logic is if t1.a is null, order by

```
t2.b asc, t2.c asc
```

t1.a, t2.b, t2.c are all INT or BIGINT. The problem is, t1.a is taken as String in sort, the result is like

```
10
100
1000
...
11
...
```

instead of

```
10
11
12
...
100
...
```

Mostly because of the concat(...) returns a String. How to solve the issue.

Comment: *"Mostly because of the concat(...) returns a String. How to solve the issue."* force it to a int? with something like `concat(t2.b, ',', t2.c) + 0`  or `cast(concat(t2.b, ',', t2.c) as unsigned)` ?

Comment: + 0 doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LPAD()` for zero padding:

```
order by
    case when t1.a is not null 
        then lpad(t1.a, 20, 0) 
        else concat(lpad(t2.b, 20, 0) , ',', lpad(t2.c, 20, 0) )
    end asc
```

Another way is to use the CASE expression twice:

```
order by
    case when a is not null 
        then a
        else b
    end asc,
    case when a is not null 
        then a
        else c
    end asc
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sDUsAJEPEYPEtZ5Ws68dGj/0)

Comment: Because it was a production release I used Paul's solution and it worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is equivalent to this:

```
order by
  case 
    when t1.a is not null 
      then t1.a 
      else t2.b
    end, 
  t2.b, 
  t2.c
```

or simply:

```
order by
  coalesce(t1.a, t2.b), 
  t2.b, 
  t2.c
```

or this:

```
order by
  coalesce(t1.a, t2.b), 
  coalesce(t1.a, t2.c)
```

Comment: Though OP's rules for comparing null and non null rows are not clear, I vote for the second query, which is actually a one-liner.

Comment: Great for a reminder to use coalesce(...). but when order by t1.a don't want to involve t2.b & c.